# How to fight Math.floor(17.83 * 100) === 1782 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm currently working on financial application that requires some special financial arithmetic up to the pennies, I've got into problem when I was doing the following computation:

```
17.83 * 100 ====> 1782.99999999999...
```

which is obviously yields `Math.floor(1782.99999999999...)` to `1782`

is there a reasonable and safe method for such kind of computation in JavaScript?

Comment: How do you obtain the value `17.83`? Is it from an input field? If so, don't parseFloat it. Avoid floating point calculations with monetary values.

Comment: so what do you want? 1782 or 1783?

Comment: Use `Math.round()`. And read something about floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Not very elegent, but : Math.floor(Math.ceil(17.83 * 100))

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome console for testing, Math.floor(Math.ceil(17.83 * 100)) not good since 17.83999 * 100 would yield to 1784

Comment: Never, ever use floating point for financial calculations. Always stick to integers (or fixed-point decimals if you have them).